# Canada TRV for conference (mexico visa rejection in the past)

Tags: canada, standard-visitor-visas, visa-rejections

i want to apply to a visitor visa for attending a conference, however i heard that visa rejections from other countries would harm my application?

so i had one tourist visa rejection from mexico 3 years ago due to not having a bank account, i was oblivious about this before as i thought that stating that i have the money in cash would be enough, i was wrong.
what can i write to better my application? i stated the reason in the cover letter, is there anything else i can do?

I really would appreciate the help, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The TRV application form for Canada asks:

> b)  Have you ever been refused a visa or permit, denied entry or ordered to leave Canada or any other country or territory?

You will have to answer "Yes" to this question, and provide details in the space provided. If you state that you were denied a visa to Mexico because you did not have a bank account, and you now have a bank account, then that should not be a problem.

If you *still* do not have a bank account, then you should be prepared for further disappointment.